# Limiting a window drag movement in Vaadin

Tags: java, user-interface, view, window, vaadin

I have a Vaadin application which contains a header and a menu bar as well. The menu bar provides options where some of which opens up a new Window much similar to a desktop MIDI application. However the window can be moved above the menu and over the header. Does anyone know how it is possible to limit the view movement to within the content area. This content area is currently a VerticalLayout.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way for doing this. I think you have couple of options:

1. Implement a callback that moves the window to right place after the drag. This is not optimal for usability as it makes the window jump around.
2. Create / extend the Vaadin's (sub-)Window drag handler to and apply limits there. Unfortunately, this is not as easy as it could be, because you have to tinker with the browser's events directly.